# How to change canvas background color on StoryBook?

Tags: reactjs, storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

```
import { addDecorator, addParameters } from "@storybook/react"; 
import { withThemesProvider } from "storybook-addon-jss-theme";
import "antd/dist/antd.css"; 
import { defaultTheme } from "./theme";
 
addParameters({
   background: [
      { name: "Default theme", value: "#ffffff", default: true },
      { name: "Dark theme", value: "#000000" },
   ],
});
 
const themes = [defaultTheme];
addDecorator(withThemesProvider(themes));
```

Comment: WHy this addParameters is not working??

Comment: Is there any way I can change the canvas background color based on Theme selection? I am using https://github.com/hipstersmoothie/storybook-dark-mod, I do use the hook to get the Default Mode